# UISegmentedControl with custom color: separator line bug

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uisegmentedcontrol

Its easy change the color of UISegmentedControl. I found various solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270526/uisegmentedcontrol-selected-segment-color), [this site](http://uihacker.blogspot.com/2010/05/iphone-uisegmentedcontrol-custom-colors.html) and the best [this solution](http://matteocaldari.it/2010/05/a-uisegmentedcontrol-with-custom-color). But none was what I want.

I tried create a simple thing and it work very easy, this was my code: (I am using the iOS 4.2, not the 5.0 and xcode 4.0.2)

```
id segment[3];
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;   
- (id)init
{
    NSArray *itens = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Option 1", @"Option 2", @"Option 3", nil];    
    segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itens];
    [segmentedControl setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 30)];
    [segmentedControl setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];
    [segmentedControl addTarget:self 
                    action:@selector(segmentedControl:) 
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];

    switch (type) {
        case type1: [segmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:0]; break;
        case type2: [segmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:1]; break;        
        case type3: [segmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:2]; break;        
    }
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        //The most important trick to work, have to retain the subviews
        segment[i] = [[[segmentedControl subviews] objectAtIndex:i] retain];
    }
    [self changeColor];
    [self addSubview:segmentedControl];
    return self;
}  

- (void)segmentedControl:(id)sender 
{
    //do some thing
    [self changeColor];
}

- (void)changeColor{ 
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        [segment[i] setTintColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    }
    int select = segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;
    [segment[select] setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];     
}
```

So it create this:

[image: first image]

Very good, then I click in `Option 2`

[image: second]

Wow, this is exacly what I want, so click in `Option 3`

[image: problem]

Now the problem, this stupid blue line (marked in red square) between `Option 1` and `Option 2`. If I click in `Option 1` again, I will have:

[image: boring]

Than the blue line appear again. This mean that every left side on old clicked segment (but not with the first) will have this blue line. If I go from right to left it not happens.

I have no idea how to solve this. How can I access this line and change your color? Or I will have to use other codes. Maybe they will have the same problem...

Comment: I had the same problem as you and spend days to find the problem. Thanks a lot friend you saved my life..!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow... When we write were in stackoverflow, we can calm down and think better. I write the answer in my ow question:

`If I go from right to left it not happens.`

This is the solution! What I have to do? Simulate this.

```
BOOL inside = FALSE;
- (void)changeColor{ 
    int old = segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
      [segment[i] setTintColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    }  
/**/inside = TRUE;
/**/for (int i=3; i>0; i--) {
/**/     //When I do this, it call "segmentedControl:"
/**/    [segmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:i];
/**/}

/**/int select = old;
    [segment[select] setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];     
    [segmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:select];    
/**/inside = FALSE;    
} 

- (void)segmentedControl:(id)sender 
{
/**/if (inside==TRUE) return;   //Ignore this calls.
    //do some thing
    [self changeColor];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I Think there is a lot easier solution.
Just clean the pointers..

```
for (int i=0; i<[self.segmentedControll.subviews count]; i++) 
{
    [[self.segmentedControll.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:nil];
    if (![[self.segmentedControll.subviews objectAtIndex:i]isSelected]) 
    {   
        UIColor *tintcolor=[UIColor blackColor];
        [[self.segmentedControll.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:tintcolor];
    } 
    else 
    {
        UIColor *tintcolor=[UIColor blueColor];
        [[self.segmentedControll.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:tintcolor];
    }
}
```

Comment: Also you have to set the colors in viewDidApear in order to have the segmented control display the intended colors when it loads. Good & easy solution.