# UIsegmentedControl setTintColor strange behaviour

Tags: iphone, ios, uisegmentedcontrol, tintcolor

I have a UISegmentedControl containing 3 options for selecting map type.  I am setting tintcolor as black as default and I want to set green color for selected segment.

Here is declaration of segmented control

```
NSArray *mapType = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Map", @"Hyb", @"Sat", nil];
    segmentedMapType = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:mapType] ;
    segmentedMapType.segmentedControlStyle =   UISegmentedControlStyleBar ;
    segmentedMapType.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    segmentedMapType.frame = CGRectMake(100, 40, 120, 40);
   // segmentedMapType.momentary = YES;
    [[[segmentedMapType subviews]objectAtIndex:0] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:.6 blue:0 alpha:1]];
    [segmentedMapType setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];

[segmentedMapType addTarget:self action:@selector(selectMap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[mapSettingsView addSubview:segmentedMapType];
```

And here is the selector method

```
-(void)selectMap:(id)sender
    {
        int index = [segmentedMapType selectedSegmentIndex];

        UIColor *newSelectedTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0 green:.6 blue:0 alpha:1.0];

        if (index==0) {
    [[[segmentedMapType subviews] objectAtIndex:2] setTintColor:newSelectedTintColor];
    [[[segmentedMapType subviews] objectAtIndex:1] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [[[segmentedMapType subviews] objectAtIndex:0] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
} else if (index==1){
    [[[segmentedMapType subviews] objectAtIndex:1] setTintColor:newSelectedTintColor];
    [[[segmentedMapType subviews] objectAtIndex:0] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [[[segmentedMapType subviews] objectAtIndex:2] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
}
else

if (index==2)
{
    [[[segmentedMapType subviews] objectAtIndex:0] setTintColor:newSelectedTintColor];
    [[[segmentedMapType subviews] objectAtIndex:1] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [[[segmentedMapType subviews] objectAtIndex:2] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
}


       }
```

This code works good on devices < iOS-5 but on >=iOS-5 problem with this is green tint color does not get applied to correct segment or sometimes to any segment. What is wrong with this code? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016331/uisegmentedcontrol-with-custom-color-separator-line-bug) question.

As mentioned there selected index is not a reliable way to assign tintcolor. I had to store their id and use them to assign tintcolor.
First store the IDs

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        //The most important trick to work, have to retain the subviews
        segment[i] = [[[segmentedMapType subviews] objectAtIndex:i] retain];
    }
```

And then use it

```
-(void)selectMap:(id)sender
{
    int index = [segmentedMapType selectedSegmentIndex];
    UIColor *newSelectedTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0 green:.7 blue:0 alpha:1.0];
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        [segment[i] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    }
    int select = segmentedMapType.selectedSegmentIndex;
    [segment[select] setTintColor:newSelectedTintColor];  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for some reason if it's done in viewDidLoad (or anywhere before viewdDidAppear) changes to tint color of single segments (maybe even the whole segmented control, not sure) are not applied until you touch the control.

Answer (score 0):

From what i know there is no default way to tint specific segment index tint color..You can only provide tint to whole segment as a whole.

Try this

http://www.framewreck.net/2010/07/custom-tintcolor-for-each-segment-of.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Shubhank. But this code worked for me in iOS-4.x, I am having problem with this code when I run it on iOS-5 device. Sorry I forgot to mention this in question. And in the link mentioned by you other developers are complaining exactly about this(works well for iOS<5).