# Customizing UISegmentedControl: how change tint color of selected segment's image?

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I've used this [extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31651983/swift-how-to-remove-border-from-segmented-control) for the `UISegmentedControl` which works as you can see [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HudW0.png)

But I want to `UISegementedControl` to work slightly differently. When I select a segment, I want the selected segment's image to change color to `colorGreyLight` instead of having the background color change to `colorGreyDark` and the selected segement image change to `UIColor.clearColor()` (as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HudW0.png))

So how can I do this?

**My Code**

UISegmented Control Extension:

```
extension UISegmentedControl {
    func removeBorders() {
        setBackgroundImage(imageWithColor(UIColor.clearColor()), forState: .Normal, barMetrics: .Default)
        setBackgroundImage(imageWithColor(tintColor), forState: .Selected, barMetrics: .Default)
        setDividerImage(imageWithColor(UIColor.clearColor()), forLeftSegmentState: .Normal, rightSegmentState: .Normal, barMetrics: .Default)
    }

    // create a 1x1 image with this color
    private func imageWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
        CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return image
    }
}
```

UISegemented Control:

```
    let types = ["rectangle", "circle", "triangle"]
    shapeSelector = UISegmentedControl(items: types)
    shapeSelector.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, sliderHeight*3 + 30, sliderHeight)
    shapeSelector.center = CGPoint(x: drawToolbar.bounds.width/2, y: sliderCenterY)
    shapeSelector.tintColor = colorGreyDark
    shapeSelector.removeBorders()
    shapeSelector.selectedSegmentIndex = 0 //default: select rectangle
    shapeSelector.addTarget(self, action: "selectShape:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
    shapeSelector.setImage(UIImage(named: "rectangle"), forSegmentAtIndex: 0)
    shapeSelector.setImage(UIImage(named: "circle"), forSegmentAtIndex: 1)
    shapeSelector.setImage(UIImage(named: "triangle"), forSegmentAtIndex: 2)
    shapeSelector.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    drawToolbar.addSubview(shapeSelector)
```

If it's any concern I'm using:

- IOS 9.2
- Swift 2
- Xcode 7.2

---

**UPDATE**
Okay so I've changed my code (as marked with comments below) as suggested by Keyur

UISegmented Control Extension:

```
extension UISegmentedControl {
    func removeBorders() {
        setBackgroundImage(imageWithColor(UIColor.clearColor()), forState: .Normal, barMetrics: .Default)
        setBackgroundImage(imageWithColor(UIColor.clearColor()), forState: .Selected, barMetrics: .Default) //change to clear color
        setDividerImage(imageWithColor(UIColor.clearColor()), forLeftSegmentState: .Normal, rightSegmentState: .Normal, barMetrics: .Default)
    }

    // create a 1x1 image with this color
    private func imageWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
        CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return image
    }
}
```

UISegemented Control:

```
    let types = ["rectangle", "circle", "triangle"]
    shapeSelector = UISegmentedControl(items: types)
    shapeSelector.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, sliderHeight*3 + 30, sliderHeight)
    shapeSelector.center = CGPoint(x: drawToolbar.bounds.width/2, y: sliderCenterY)
    shapeSelector.tintColor = colorGreyDark
    shapeSelector.removeBorders()
    shapeSelector.selectedSegmentIndex = 0 //default: select rectangle
    (shapeSelector.subviews[0] as UIView).tintColor = colorGreyLight //added this line
    shapeSelector.addTarget(self, action: "selectShape:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
    shapeSelector.setImage(UIImage(named: "rectangle"), forSegmentAtIndex: 0)
    shapeSelector.setImage(UIImage(named: "circle"), forSegmentAtIndex: 1)
    shapeSelector.setImage(UIImage(named: "triangle"), forSegmentAtIndex: 2)
    shapeSelector.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    drawToolbar.addSubview(shapeSelector)
```

`selectShape()` function:

```
func selectShape(sender: UISegmentedControl){
    switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex{
    case 0: //rectangle
        shapeType = "rectangle"
        (sender.subviews[0] as UIView).tintColor = colorGreyLight
        (sender.subviews[1] as UIView).tintColor = colorGreyDark
        (sender.subviews[2] as UIView).tintColor = colorGreyDark
    case 1: //circle
        shapeType = "circle"
        (sender.subviews[0] as UIView).tintColor = colorGreyDark
        (sender.subviews[1] as UIView).tintColor = colorGreyLight
        (sender.subviews[2] as UIView).tintColor = colorGreyDark
    case 2: //triangle
        shapeType = "triangle"
        (sender.subviews[0] as UIView).tintColor = colorGreyDark
        (sender.subviews[1] as UIView).tintColor = colorGreyDark
        (sender.subviews[2] as UIView).tintColor = colorGreyLight
    default:
        shapeType = "rectangle"
        (sender.subviews[0] as UIView).tintColor = colorGreyLight
        (sender.subviews[1] as UIView).tintColor = colorGreyDark
        (sender.subviews[2] as UIView).tintColor = colorGreyDark
    }
}
```

Except when I try it, the selected shape is not always the one highlighted as you can see [here](http://screencast.com/t/X5tREuST). It seems to be almost randomly highlighting the shapes and I don't understand why.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my answer thanks to [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910074/uisegmentedcontrol-settintcolor-strange-behaviour)

Apparently selected index is not a reliable way to assign tint color. Instead I had to keep track of the segments myself.

So that's what I did after I created my `UISegmentedControl shapeSelector`:

```
var segments: [UIView] = [UIView]()
for i in 0...shapeSelector.subviews.count-1{
    segments.append(shapeSelector.subviews[i])
}
```

And in my `UISegmentedControl`'s function I did:

```
func selectShape(sender: UISegmentedControl){
    let i = sender.selectedSegmentIndex
    for s in segments{
        s.tintColor = colorGreyDark
    }
    segments[i].tintColor = colorGreyLight

    switch i{
    case 0:
        shapeType = "rectangle"
    case 1:
        shapeType = "circle"
    case 2:
        shapeType = "triangle"
    default:
        shapeType = "rectangle"
    }
}
```

Now everything works perfectly!

---

**Full Code**

```
extension UISegmentedControl {
    func removeBorders() {
        setBackgroundImage(imageWithColor(UIColor.clearColor()), forState: .Normal, barMetrics: .Default)
        setBackgroundImage(imageWithColor(UIColor.clearColor()), forState: .Selected, barMetrics: .Default)
        setDividerImage(imageWithColor(UIColor.clearColor()), forLeftSegmentState: .Normal, rightSegmentState: .Normal, barMetrics: .Default)
}

    // create a 1x1 image with this color
    private func imageWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
        CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return image
    }
}

class DrawViewController: UIViewController {

    var shapeSelector: UISegmentedControl = UISegmentedControl()
    var segments: [UIView] = [UIView]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //set up shape selector
        let types = ["rectangle", "circle", "triangle"]
        shapeSelector = UISegmentedControl(items: types)
        shapeSelector.frame = CGRectMake(shapeTypeLabel.frame.maxX + sliderSpace, 0, sliderHeight*3 + 30, sliderHeight)
        shapeSelector.center.y = shapeTypeLabel.center.y
        shapeSelector.tintColor = colorGreyDark
        shapeSelector.removeBorders()
        shapeSelector.addTarget(self, action: "selectShape:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
        shapeSelector.setImage(UIImage(named: "rectangle"), forSegmentAtIndex: 0)
        shapeSelector.setImage(UIImage(named: "circle"), forSegmentAtIndex: 1)
        shapeSelector.setImage(UIImage(named: "triangle"), forSegmentAtIndex: 2)
        for i in 0...shapeSelector.subviews.count-1{
            segments.append(shapeSelector.subviews[i])
        }
        shapeSelector.selectedSegmentIndex = 0 //default: select rectangle
        segments[0].tintColor = colorGreyLight
        shapeSelector.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
        drawToolbar.addSubview(shapeSelector)
    }

    func selectShape(sender: UISegmentedControl){
        let i = sender.selectedSegmentIndex
        for s in segments{
            s.tintColor = colorGreyDark
        }
        segments[i].tintColor = colorGreyLight

        switch i{
        case 0:
            shapeType = "rectangle"
        case 1:
            shapeType = "circle"
        case 2:
            shapeType = "triangle"
        default:
            shapeType = "rectangle"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(shapeSelector.subviews[2] as UIView).tintColor = UIColor .redColor()
(shapeSelector.subviews[1] as UIView).tintColor = UIColor .redColor()
(shapeSelector.subviews[0] as UIView).tintColor = UIColor .redColor()
```

Comment: I've changed my code as you suggested. Thank-you for that. Except now the selected shape is not always the one highlighted. Do you know why that would be?

Answer (score 1):

1. set colors in your removeborders() function.

setBackgroundImage(imageWithColor(UIColor.clearColor()), forState: .Normal, barMetrics: .Default)
        setBackgroundImage(imageWithColor(UIColor.lightGrayColor()), forState: .Selected, barMetrics: .Default)