# How to find the subview that is the selected control segment?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270526/uisegmentedcontrol-selected-segment-color) and wondering how it was known or where it is documented that `[[segmentedControl subviews] objectAtIndex:0]` is the currently selected control segment?

That is - how do we know which `objectAtIndex` number to use?

Comment: No where it is mention that [[segmentedControl subviews] objectAtIndex:0] will only be the selected segment.Based on property value isSelected which returns BOOL value it is decided which segment is selected.for (int i=0; i<[sender.subviews count]; i++) 
{
    if ([[sender.subviews objectAtIndex:i]isSelected] ) 
    {               
    UIColor *tintcolor=[UIColor colorWithRed:127.0/255.0 green:161.0/255.0 blue:183.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    [[sender.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:tintcolor];
    break;
    }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at other responses, you see that they look for the one that is selected, that is, check what `isSelected` returns

```
for (int i = 0; i < [sender.subviews count]; i++) 
{
  if ([[sender.subviews objectAtIndex:i]isSelected]) 
  {               
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to say that the code Frowing mentioned may crash. class checking is needed.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < [sender.subviews count]; i++) {
         UIView *seg = [sender.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
             if ([seg isKindOfClass:[UISegmentedControl class]]&&[seg isSelected]) 
             {               
             ...
             }
         }
```