# Change the color of selected segment control

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

In my app,i able to change the color of the selected segment control.But the color is changed for another index rather than selected index. I can find any mistake in the index.

Help me!

my code is as follow:

```
if([SegmentRound selectedSegmentIndex] == 0)
    {

        UIColor *newSelectedTintColor2 = [UIColor colorWithRed: 98/255.0 green:156/255.0 blue:247/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        [[[SegmentRound subviews] objectAtIndex:0] setTintColor:newSelectedTintColor2];

        UIColor *newSelectedTintColor1 = [UIColor colorWithRed: 54/255.0 green:52/255.0 blue:48/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        [[[SegmentRound subviews] objectAtIndex:1] setTintColor:newSelectedTintColor1];

        UIColor *newSelectedTintColor0 = [UIColor colorWithRed: 54/255.0 green:52/255.0 blue:48/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        [[[SegmentRound subviews] objectAtIndex:2] setTintColor:newSelectedTintColor0];



        FLAGROUND=1;
    }

    if([SegmentRound selectedSegmentIndex] == 1)
    {
        UIColor *newSelectedTintColor1 = [UIColor colorWithRed: 98/255.0 green:156/255.0 blue:247/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        [[[SegmentRound subviews] objectAtIndex:1] setTintColor:newSelectedTintColor1];

        UIColor *newSelectedTintColor0 = [UIColor colorWithRed: 54/255.0 green:52/255.0 blue:48/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        [[[SegmentRound subviews] objectAtIndex:0] setTintColor:newSelectedTintColor0];

        UIColor *newSelectedTintColor2 = [UIColor colorWithRed: 54/255.0 green:52/255.0 blue:48/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        [[[SegmentRound subviews] objectAtIndex:2] setTintColor:newSelectedTintColor2];

        FLAGROUND=2;
    }
    if([SegmentRound selectedSegmentIndex] == 2)
    {
        UIColor *newSelectedTintColor0 = [UIColor colorWithRed: 98/255.0 green:156/255.0 blue:247/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        [[[SegmentRound subviews] objectAtIndex:2] setTintColor:newSelectedTintColor0];

        UIColor *newSelectedTintColor2 = [UIColor colorWithRed: 54/255.0 green:52/255.0 blue:48/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        [[[SegmentRound subviews] objectAtIndex:0] setTintColor:newSelectedTintColor2];

        UIColor *newSelectedTintColor1 = [UIColor colorWithRed: 54/255.0 green:52/255.0 blue:48/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        [[[SegmentRound subviews] objectAtIndex:1] setTintColor:newSelectedTintColor1];
        FLAGROUND=3;
    }
```

viewwillAppear:

```
[SegmentRound setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];
```

Comment: you can directly apply color in nib fil. why you manage through coding?

Comment: i want display different color rather than dark and blue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd recommend to create the two colors outside of your condition, makes your code a bit smaller. Then you can use a foreach to iterate over your segments :

```
UIColor *selectedColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 98/255.0 green:156/255.0 blue:247/255.0 alpha:1.0];
UIColor *deselectedColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 54/255.0 green:52/255.0 blue:48/255.0 alpha:1.0];

for (UIControl *subview in [SegmentRound subviews]) {
    if ([subview isSelected]) 
       [subview setTintColor:selectedColor]; 
    else
       [subview setTintColor:deselectedColor]; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

check out this one

```
-(IBAction)segmentBtnPressed:(UISegmentedControl*)sender{
for (int i=0; i<[sender.subviews count]; i++) 
{
    if ([[sender.subviews objectAtIndex:i]isSelected] ) 
    {               
    UIColor *tintcolor=[UIColor colorWithRed: 98/255.0 green:156/255.0 blue:247/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    [[sender.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:tintcolor];
    }
    else{
     UIColor *tintcolor=[UIColor colorWithRed:127.0/255.0 green:161.0/255.0 blue:183.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    [[sender.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:tintcolor];

    }
}
}
```

Also you can check out more answers here [UISegmentedControl selected segment color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270526/uisegmentedcontrol-selected-segment-color/5932524#5932524)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can simply change the TintColor of Segment Control. It works perfectly for me.

Answer (score -1):

I tried printing subviews of segment control on console and I detected that indexes are in reverse order, means if selectedSegment is 0 then your subview should be 2 not 0.Try printing segment control on console and you will see the same result as follows on segment action.:

```
NSArray *theArr = [mSegmentedControl subviews];
            DEBUGLOG(@"controls arr: %@",theArr);
```

Logs on console:

```
controls arr: (
    "<UISegment: 0x8598ad0; frame = (77 0; 76 34); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8598b30>>",
    "<UISegment: 0x85986e0; frame = (0 0; 76 34); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8598740>>"
)
```