# how to set color for only selected segment index in segment controller

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xcode4.2, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a UISegment controller,In this controller I want to change the selected segment controller tab color to orange.Other tab will be normal gray color.
Please help me how to achieve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270526/uisegmentedcontrol-selected-segment-color http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103961/change-the-color-of-selected-segment-control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple way to get this using  `UISegmentedControl appearance`

```
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                         [UIColor orangeColor],UITextAttributeTextColor, nil]
                                               forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Comment: Hi viruss,Its working for text is fine,But I want the segment color change instead of blue(default color).