# how to set color for segments in segemented control for selected state in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm using segmented control instead of buttons. how to set the background colour for selected segment. am trying to change background color but it color appears all segments.

Comment: Pl. post your code...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the color of selected segment control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103961/change-the-color-of-selected-segment-control)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried sample one for your question.I set the segment control in XIB.Also I set three titles.I hooked up the segment to ViewController.h with properties and action.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentBgColorChange;
- (IBAction)actionChangeBGColor:(id)sender;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
{
}
@end
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize segmentBgColorChange;

// Then in action methods

- (IBAction)actionChangeBGColor:(id)sender
{
  UISegmentedControl *seg = sender;
  for (int i=0; i<[seg.subviews count]; i++) {
    if ([[seg.subviews objectAtIndex:i]isSelected]) {
        UIColor *bgColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [[seg.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:bgColor];
    } else {
        [[seg.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:nil];
    }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set the 1st index selected then write this code.

```
[segmentControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];
```

If you set the background color then write this code

```
UIColor *selectedColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
   for (UIControl *subview in [segmentControl subviews]) {

        [subview setTintColor:selectedColor];

    }
```

If you change the tint color and font size then write this code.

```
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0f]};
[segmentControl setTitleTextAttributes:attributes
                              forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[segmentControl setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14.0],
                                         NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]}
                              forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[segmentControl setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14.0],
                                         NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor]}
                              forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```