# customize color for selected segmented in segmented control

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios6, background-color, uisegmentedcontrol

How can I customize/change color for selected segmented in segmented control? I tried to use method available at [UISegmentedControl selected segment color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270526/uisegmentedcontrol-selected-segment-color) . It worked perfectly with iOS 5 and below but not for iOS 6. Any help is appreciated.

Basically I am looking to change color for the selected segmented to some bright color so that selected/unselected segments are clearly visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the subclass of that particular view and then override its drawRect() method for its custom appearance on the screen.

Answer (score 4):

We used the approach mentioned by siddarth.

Subclass the segmented controller and overriding the drawrect() method. Something like this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
[super drawRect:rect];

for (int i=0; i<[self.subviews count]; i++)
{
    if ([[self.subviews objectAtIndex:i]isSelected] )
    {
        UIColor *tintcolor=[UIColor redColor];
        [[self.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:tintcolor];
    } else {
        UIColor *tintcolor=[UIColor grayColor]; // default color
        [[self.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:tintcolor];
    }
   }

}
```