# Change Existing Set UIColors on UIButton Press

Tags: ios, iphone, uibutton, uitextview

The objective is to change the font color and background color of my UITextView upon UIButton click and then revert them back to the original colors when the UIButton is clicked again; then repeat, ect.

[image: Screenshot]

Default Color Settings

- Text: `blackColor`
- Background: `lightGrayColor`

Upon Button Click (change to..)

- Text: `greenColor`
- Background: `blackColor`

(then if clicked again, change back to default color settings)

So far I have this:

```
- (IBAction) enableSleepMode:(id)sender {

    [txtNotes setTextColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [txtNotes setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

}
```

I apologize but I'm not exactly sure where to go from here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly isn't working?  That code seems like it would work to set it to green/black?  You could do a `if (txtNotes.textColor == [UIColor greenColor])` to determine what state its in and swap back and forth...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said to change the font color and background color of '`UITextView`' not '`UIButton`' Right? . Then did you add `UItextViewDelegate`?

I have done this like

**EDIT:**

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [txtView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [txtView setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    str = @"first";
    }

   -(IBAction)bt:(id)sender
{
    if([str isEqualToString:@"first"])
    {
        [txtView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [txtView setTextColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        str = @"second";
    }
    else
    {
       [txtView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
       [txtView setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];  
        str = @"first";
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah! This is beautiful, thank you! I apologize if I did not make this clear in my original post. I'll try this out tonight when I get access to my work station.

Comment: it now says that `Property 'selected' not found on object UIBarButtonItem` http://content.screencast.com/users/revblaze/folders/Jing/media/a689747a-353b-4eb5-8c22-aab0e1fe842c/00000089.png

Comment: Note: I do have all sent actions and referencing outlets connected.

Comment: @MattBush You said its UIButton in the question. I don't think UIbarButton have selected property. You could do it with bar button like this . Check my edited code. Its very straight forward approach though. In the edited code 'str' is an NSString variable. Declare it in .h file

Comment: Worked beautifully. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 (void)setTextColor:(UIColor *)color forState:(UIControlState)state

[button setTextColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

 (void)setBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)color forState:(UIControlState)state

[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightgrayColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

something like that is i think what you're looking for

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I was looking for! Now how do I implement this because no matter where I add it, I return 2 errors: `Use of undeclared identifier setTextColor` and `Use of undeclared identified setBackgroundColor`

Not that it is currently under my _enableSleepMode_ IBAction.

Comment: funny. did you rename button appropriately? I know it works fir title/bar. there is a more complex way of doing it. see http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-uitextfield-uitextfielddelegate/. In their example, the background changes to green when the text field is active. it involves adding a boolean value.

Comment: on the other hand see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270526/uisegmentedcontrol-selected-segment-color/5932524#5932524