# How to remove white bar beside segmented control

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I have two UISegmentedControls over a mapView.

[image]

You can see a white background on the right side of the second control, that I am not able to remove.
Any help is welcome.

Comment: @Aaron The better question would be how was the segmented control created? I've never seen such a thing.

Comment: That's true. Neither have I.

Comment: @rmaddy, it is a normal UISegmentedControl with 3 segments.

Comment: I get it. He wants a white background (not the default) with no bleed-through. He needs do what Martin suggests.

Comment: yes @Aaron, thats what I want, a white background only inside the control.

Comment: Have you tried what Martin has suggested?

Comment: @Aaron, yes, the corner radius is not the solution, the corner do decrease, but the rest of the white bar doesn't.

Comment: It looks like you've got a wacky springs/struts issue or even an AutoLayout problem. Can you share a little more about how you've set this control up in the Storyboard, XIB and implementation file? Any and all relevant code will be helpful

Comment: Thank you @Aaron, I decided to move the second segmented control outside the mapView, just below the first segmented control. The problem may be with overlapping the mapview.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To avoid the ugly white sharp corners you need to do this:

```
self.segmentControl.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
```

and then play with the segmented control width to avoid the white space on the right side. Just try to decrese/increase the size by 1 pt in steps until it disappears.

Comment: The ugly sharp white corners don't come default with iOS 7's segmented controls. They have a transparent background. There's something else going on here.

Comment: Well, I don't know where are they comming from, but I was in the same situation and what I write solved my problem for the case you want white or some sort of semi-transparent background for the control.

Comment: Your proposal is fine, then the corner radius decreases, but the rest of the bar doesn't.

Comment: In order to remove the white background on the right side, just decrese the width of the control by 1 point, then try decreasing it by 2 points etc. until it disappears. Don't really know the background of this, but when I faced it I thought Apple draws the control slightly smaller in order to draw the deviding lines on whole points and no fractions of points which would make the lines blurry. If this is true, then number of segments will play role as well. Did not tested but for 3 segments try width as a whole multiply of 3.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the Background to default. The default background should be transparent.

Comment: thank you, but I want to have a white background, not a transparent one.

Comment: Have you tried this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351808/customize-uisegmentedcontrol-add-background-image-and-selected-segment-tint-col
?