# how to change the tint color of disable segment in UISegmentedControl

Tags: objective-c, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

How to change the tint color of disable segment in UISegmentedControl.
I got the solution to sort the segmentedControl.subviews , below is the swift code, please convert it to objective c.

```
@IBAction func indexChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {

let sortedViews = sender.subviews.sort( { $0.frame.origin.x < $1.frame.origin.x } )

for (index, view) in sortedViews.enumerate() {
    if index == sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
        view.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    } else {
        view.tintColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    }
}

}

let sortedViews = segmentedControlOutletVariable.subviews.sort( { $0.frame.origin.x < $1.frame.origin.x } )
sortedViews[0].tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following code:

1.It assigns green colour to selected segment.(segment-2)

2.Assigns blue colour to those not selected but enabled(segment-1 and 3).

3.Assigns lightGray colour for segments which are disabled.(segment-4)

```
-(IBAction)segmentedTapped:(UISegmentedControl*)sender{

for(int i=0;i<[sender.subviews count];i++)
{
    if ([[sender.subviews objectAtIndex:i]isEnabled])
    {


        if([[sender.subviews objectAtIndex:i]isSelected])
        {
            UIColor *tintcolor=[UIColor greenColor];
            [[sender.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:tintcolor]; //sets green color for selected segment which is enabled
        }
        else
        {
            [[sender.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]]; //sets blue colour for remaining segments which are enabled but not selected.

        }
    }
    else
    {
        [[sender.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];//sets ight gray for disabled segment.
    }
}
}
```

The result will be:
[image]

if you want more information you can get from here:

[UISegmentedControl selected segment color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270526/uisegmentedcontrol-selected-segment-color)

Comment: Actually i want to change the tint color of disabled segment..please help

Comment: how to sort the segmentcontrol subviews array indexes?

Comment: @jasonfrank: my code will assign light gray to disabled segment. Yo can set there which colour u want.

Comment: suppose we have 3 segments and in which one is selected, second is not selected but enable and  third is disable, now i want tint color for third one to gray