# UISegment selected/unselected color in xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

My app has separate code and bundle (xib are to be downloaded separately). I can't change my code yet and I have to change xib file.

On ios 7, I can see correctly like this when I change in my xib.

[image]

[image]

With that setting, on my ios 6, selected color and unselected color become same (black). User can't differentiate.

[image]

How can I change in my xib so that behaviour is correct? (I can't change my code for now. I can only change xib). If Tint color is default, it is okay but I still need it to be black color.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270526/uisegmentedcontrol-selected-segment-color

Comment: Thanks. but I can't change my code (I got restriction to change). I have to change in xib or xib need to support for each OS (like size class).

Comment: create dulpiacte Xib and your code

Answer (score 0):

you are setting tint color, which is correct approach. It’s background color is white that means it’s default color and you are setting black color as tint color so it is also fine.

So make sure that your `SegmentControl`’s style is `plain` and `state` is not `checked` beside `Momentary`. Make sure that state is unchecked. If it is checked then uncheck it. You can check all this under `attribute inspector` with your segmented control selected.